# Subtracting previous row using mysql update

Tags: mysql, subtraction, cumulative-sum

Table in database

| date | amount | name | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-01 | 10.00 | john doe | 1002 |
| 12-02 | 10.00 | john doe | 1003 |
| 11-01 | 50.00 | john doe | 8976 |
| 11-02 | 50.00 | john doe | 8977 |
| 09-01 | 50.00 | john doe | 6788 |
| 09-02 | 50.00 | john doe | 6799 |
| 09-02 | 50.00 | alicia doe | 6800 |

Result should be like this:

| Month | amount | total increase/decrease | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| September | 100.00 | 100.00 | john doe |
| November | 100.00 | 0 | john doe |
| December | 20.00 | -80.00 | john doe |

Comment: `12-01` is not a `date`

Comment: The `total increase/descrease` is taking from the previous value is it?

Comment: Yes sir that is right, but i have an error when im using LAG(sum(amount))

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a query like this

```
SELECT a1.pdate
 , SUM(a1.amount) AS amount
 , SUM(a1.total) AS total
 , a1.username AS username
FROM (
  SELECT a.*, COALESCE(a.amount+LAG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY pdate),0) AS total
  FROM am a 
  ORDER BY pdate
) AS a1
GROUP BY username,MONTH(pdate);
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from am;
+----+------------+--------+----------+
| id | pdate      | amount | username |
+----+------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 2021-12-01 |  10.00 | john doe |
|  2 | 2021-12-02 |  10.00 | john doe |
|  3 | 2021-11-01 |  50.00 | john doe |
|  4 | 2021-11-02 |  50.00 | john doe |
+----+------------+--------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT a1.pdate
    ->  , SUM(a1.amount) AS amount
    ->  , SUM(a1.total) AS total
    ->  , a1.username AS username
    -> FROM (
    ->   SELECT a.*, COALESCE(a.amount+LAG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY pdate),0) AS total
    ->   FROM am a 
    ->   ORDER BY pdate
    -> ) AS a1
    -> GROUP BY username,MONTH(pdate);
+------------+--------+--------+----------+
| pdate      | amount | total  | username |
+------------+--------+--------+----------+
| 2021-11-01 | 100.00 | 100.00 | john doe |
| 2021-12-01 |  20.00 |  80.00 | john doe |
+------------+--------+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: I'm using the exact query on my actual database but dont know why i cant display my desired result. The result is something like this 2021-09-01 5000000 0- 1st row 2021-11-03 164631903.07 334260806.14 -2nd row 2021-12-01 100177708.91 200348297.17- 3rd row 3rd column is the problem

Comment: @FanoFN hi sir  i dont know what's the reason behind this but i have an error in LAG(sum(amount)) it is not working. But when i remove the sum on this part the query is working properly, on that reason without sum on the query i cannot get the result that i want. If there is other way to get the same result without using LAG or any diff approach. Hope you can help me thank u.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Last_trans) AS Month,
       name,
       total,
       prevTotal,
       total-IFNULL(prevTotal,0) AS Diff
FROM
(SELECT MAX(date) Last_trans,
       MONTH(date) mth,
       name,
       SUM(amount) total,
       LAG(SUM(amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY MONTH(date)) prevTotal
FROM mytable
GROUP BY MONTH(date), name) V;
```

Based on my testing, this works for MySQL v8.0.27 as in this [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7a42e6498d254130fc669fbe9e784ed). On MariaDB however, this will return `Invalid use of group function` error message. On that note, you can separate the `SUM()` and `LAG()` operation into two subqueries:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Last_trans) AS Month,
       name,
       total,
       prevTotal,
       total-IFNULL(prevTotal,0) AS Diff
FROM
(SELECT Last_trans,
        mth,
        name,
        total,
        LAG(total) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY mth) prevTotal
  FROM
     (SELECT MAX(date) Last_trans,
             MONTH(date) mth,
             name,
             SUM(amount) total
       FROM mytable
       GROUP BY MONTH(date), name) V 
  ) T
```

[Fiddle for MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bd97a35635d5d2f7a4b08875b4b6a312)

Comment: ,hi sir  i dont know what's the reason behind this but i have an error in LAG(sum(amount)) it is not working. But when i remove the sum on this part the query is working properly, on that reason without sum on the query i cannot get the result that i want. If there is other way to get the same result without using LAG or any diff approach. Hope you can help me thank u.

Comment: @PapsiRhty , can you run `SELECT version();` and post the exact version of your MySQL server here?